# How does one resolve link error with Qt?

Tags: qt, linker

I'm new to Qt, and trying to compile and link a simple "Hello, World" program using Microsoft's "CL.exe".  Any advice on how to do this?

The program is:

```
#include <QtGui>

int main ( int argc, char * argv [] )
    {
    QApplication app ( argc, argv ) ;
    QLabel label ( "Hello, world!" ) ;
    label.show() ;
    return app.exec() ;
    }
```

I compile and link with:

```
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.0\VC\bin\cl.EXE -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -O2 -MD ^
-W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICODE ^
-DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB ^
-DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DYNAMIC_CAST ^
-I"C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\include\QtCore" ^
-I"C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\include\QtGui" ^
-I"C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\include" ^
-I"." ^
-I"C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\include\ActiveQt" ^
-I"release" ^
-I"C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008" ^
-I"C:\Progra~1\MICROS~1.0\VC\include" ^
Hello.cpp ^
/link /LIBPATH:"C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\lib" ^
/LIBPATH:"C:\Progra~1\MICROS~1.0\VC\lib" ^
/LIBPATH:"C:\Progra~1\MID05A~1\VC\PLATFO~1\Lib"
```

My linker errors include:

```
Hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) pub
lic: virtual __thiscall QApplication::~QApplication(void)" (__imp_??1QApplicatio
n@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
Hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) pub
lic: virtual __thiscall QLabel::~QLabel(void)" (__imp_??1QLabel@@UAE@XZ) referen
ced in function _main
Hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) pub
lic: static int __cdecl QApplication::exec(void)" (__imp_?exec@QApplication@@SAH
XZ) referenced in function _main
Hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) pub
lic: void __thiscall QWidget::show(void)" (__imp_?show@QWidget@@QAEXXZ) referenc
ed in function _main
.
.
.
```

My Hello.pro file contains:

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (2.01a) Mon Dec 13 15:58:13 2010
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = 
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
SOURCES += Hello.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be linking against QtCore and QtGui libraries but you don't. What does your .pro file look like?

---

Edited to add after the .pro file was posted: Your .pro file looks all right. You're not overwriting the `QT` variable which by default includes `core gui`, which should result in QtCode and QtGui being linked to. It's also evident by the fact that both QtCore and QtGui are present in your include paths.

I haven't used cl.exe with Qt but you could try adding `LIBS += -lQtCore -lQtGui` to force linking to QtCore and QtGui. (There's probably a more elegant fix though.)

Comment: Hello.pro now included in the question.

Comment: Answer:  Compile the libraries using Microsoft's compiler using Visual Studio projects C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\src\corelib\QtCore.vcproj and C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\src\gui\QtGui.vcproj.  Then, create Hello project in Visual Studio, and, under Project ... Properties, add directories under "C/C++...Additional Include Directories", add "...qt\lib" directory under "Linker...General...Additional Library Directories", add "QtCored4.lib and QtGuid4.lib" under "Linker...Input...Additional Dependencies."  Then, build project.  {Hope I remembered everything!}

Answer (score 0):

Your PATH should include the qt/bin directory. In a Visual Studio Command Prompt you should do a "qmake hello.pro" which creates three makefiles, and then "nmake". If you want to use vcxproj files, you should change your TEMPLATE to **vcapp**.

Answer (score 0):

> trying to compile and link a simple
>   "Hello, World" program using
>   Microsoft's "CL.exe"

Hey i think there are easier ways of getting qt applications compiled on visual studio. Instead of struggling with commandline options why not [install the qt visual studio addin](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/visual-studio-add-in) that makes compiling projects soooooooo easy? Just a suggestion :)